# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=3 out of bounds (limit=6, nb=4)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Code

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.getDouble())
```

I am trying to pass Uint24 containing 2 bytes into a variable using above code.
But it crashes giving me error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=3 out of bounds (limit=6, nb=4)
```

For single byte I am using short like `bb.getShort();`

Please someone could explain me on how to do it.

Comment: Did you try with `bb.getDouble(0);` ?

Comment: Yup that's what I tried. I tried float and long as well. Nothing working so far

Comment: How about `bb.rewind();` and then `bb.getDouble();`

Comment: Okay, I will try

Comment: And also add this info into your question `System.out.println(bb.toString());`...just paste the output.

Comment: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=6].. This is the output

Comment: I need data in three different bytes . .. 1) Uint 8  2) Uint16 3) Uint 24

Answer (score 3):

This error could be caused by the corrupted **font**.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue after undo deleting fonts, I've re-add the fonts again and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let's note: the **getDouble()** tries to read **eight** bytes at the current index, so perhaps there aren't so much data in the array (**limit=6**).
2. I think we should use the **asIntBuffer()** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer()) in yours case.

Bests )